# Hyperlink to cross-reference two tables

Tags: excel

How can I combine these hyperlinks into one that will cross-reference whichever of References or Citations exists?

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("#" & CELL("address", INDEX(INDIRECT("References[Reference]"), MATCH([@Resource], INDIRECT("References[Resource]"), 0))), "References"), "")

=IFERROR(HYPERLINK("#" & CELL("address", INDEX(INDIRECT("Citations[Citation]"), MATCH([@Resource], INDIRECT("Citations[Resource]"), 0))), "Citations"), "")
```

Comment: Why the INDIRECTs?

Comment: They are not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Resources table use this to link to the References table.

```
=HYPERLINK(TEXT(ADDRESS(MATCH([@Resource], References[Reference], 0)+ROW(References[#Headers]), COLUMN(References[Reference]), 4, 1, CELL("filename", References[#All])), "\#@"), "References")
```

To link from the Resources table to the Citations table.

```
=HYPERLINK(TEXT(ADDRESS(MATCH([@Resource], Citations[Citation], 0)+ROW(Citations[#Headers]), COLUMN(Citations[Citation]), 4, 1, CELL("filename", Citations[#All])), "\#@"), "Citations")
```

Combined.

```
=iferror(iferror(HYPERLINK(TEXT(ADDRESS(MATCH([@Resource], References[Reference], 0)+ROW(References[#Headers]), COLUMN(References[Reference]), 4, 1, CELL("filename", References[#All])), "\#@"), "References"), HYPERLINK(TEXT(ADDRESS(MATCH([@Resource], Citations[Citation], 0)+ROW(Citations[#Headers]), COLUMN(Citations[Citation]), 4, 1, CELL("filename", Citations[#All])), "\#@"), "Citations")), TEXT(,))
```

Those address constructions do include the worksheet name in case the tables are on different worksheets.

Comment: I still have two separate hyperlinks; whereas I am looking to combine the two into one that will adapt to whichever of References or Citations exists.

Comment: Just nest one within the IFERROR of the other.

Comment: Thank you: nesting one within the IFERROR of the other is what I was after.